# "PlaySound()" Function Playing Default Windows Error Sound

Tags: c++

I am a high school student working on learning some C++ on the side of school. I am currently looking into playing sounds in C++ programs. I am trying to use the "PlaySound()" function to do so. I have looked at the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680.aspx) for this function, as well as looking on Stack Exchange, and watching a video. Unfortunately, when I compile this code I am met with the default windows error sound. I would love some help figuring out what is going wrong with this program.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    PlaySound(TEXT("bird.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume that the `bird.wav` file is in the folder where your executable is. Are you sure about this?

Comment: "The pszSound parameter is a file name. **If the file cannot be found, the function plays the default sound**". It seems that system can't find "bird.wav". First of all, try to use full path to this file (like "d:\\bird.wav").

Comment: Before anything else, if you're running this from the Visual Studio IDE, put the .wav file in your *project* folder. That's the folder with your .vcproj file is located, and is the default working directory when launched from the gui.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That appears to have been the problem. When I moved the sound into the project file it worked like I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that bird.wav was not in the Visual Studio project file. I moved it there and the sound played correctly.